# How to build web.xml for Dropwizard application

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web, dropwizard

I have created application in Dropwizard, which is serving REST API to my clients. I used to run this from .jar file on server, everything worked fine.

Now I have requirement to move my application to WildFly, so now I assume that I need to have a WAR instead of JAR, and here comes my problem:

How to write web.xml to my application? What to include in there? Could anyone give me any template or tutorial or some example how it is done in Dropwizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. It's [wizard-in-a-box](https://github.com/rvs-fluid-it/wizard-in-a-box) project that do all the necessary things to build a WAR file.